# Android library assembles with Gradle but "package R does not exist" error raise on connectedCheck

Tags: android, automated-tests, build-process, gradle

I have an android library with the file structure below.

```
Android_Library
├── libs
└── src
    ├── instrumentTest
    │   ├── assets
    │   └── java
    └── main
        ├── aidl
        ├── gen
        ├── java
        └── res
```

When I assemble the library with Gradle, the task runs successfully. However, when I try running a connectedCheck I get the following errors about the R file not being found:

```
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug
:assembleDebug
:prepareTestDependencies
:compileTestAidl
:processTestTestManifest
:generateTestBuildConfig
:mergeTestAssets
:compileTestRenderscript
:mergeTestResources
:processTestResources
:compileTest


 Android_Library/src/instrumentTest/java/com/example/library/util/UtilTests.java:514: error: package R does not exist
                        case R.plurals.time_days_ago: {
                              ^
        ...

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
18 errors
:compileTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTest'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I originally thought that it was a problem in the R resource generation, but then I would expect it to also fail when assembling.

Edit:

I have tried both having and R import statement (which I know is incorrect) and not having and R import statement. Both result in the same error.

SOLVED:

Thanks to @Xav's tip (below): I'm extracting a library from a larger project and attempting to build it on its own for modular testing.

Changing the

`import com.example.app.R;`

statements in the library files to

`com.example.library.R`

allows the connected check to run.

(apparently the res files for both the main app and the library are the same).

Additional notes:

Since the switch statement takes in R id's the switch statement works when it compiles. However, I am still unsure of why `gradlew assemble` works with the incorrect `import` statements while `gradlew connectedCheck` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this seem unrelated to the error, I see you are doing a switch statement using IDs coming from the R class, but you are in a library.

This is not possible because those IDs are not final.

I'm wondering if that's the error but the compiler is confused and outputs a different error message.

Comment: Thanks @Xav, your suggestion pointed me in the correct direction. Still unclear of the previous gradle behavior, however, (see edit to question).